# Managing GIT and Perforce simultaneously

Tags: git, github, version-control, perforce

I have a strange requirement that I wish to manage our code base on both GIT and perforce. That said its the same code but with minor differences. The minor differences are from build scripts (ant).

Is there a better way to manage this ?

Currently, I am using DiffMerge to manually move from PERFORCE -> GIT. This would not work for a longer period as its very tedious and involves lot of manual work to resolve files.

I wonder if any one have got in to similar problems and found better solutions. If this question is already asked, Please sight the ref.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not [git fusion](http://www.perforce.com/git)?

Answer (score 2):

According to your problem statement,You can check for [git swarm](http://www.perforce.com/git).( i am not sure about this , but please take a look)